# How to shorten this placeholder-transitioning CSS selector using sass/compass?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass, compass-sass

So I decided to make a pretty animating search box ([demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/xeuea718)) with CSS transitions using SASS. I also wanted to animate the placeholder text, which involves [four different pesudo-classes](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/), and the source now looks like this:

```
input {
  background-image:url(search.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:20px 20px;
  background-position-x:12px;
  background-position-y:10px;
  background-color:#6E597E;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #333 inset;
  border-radius:15px;
  border:0;
  padding:8px 10px 10px 45px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:300;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#BBB;
  width:100%;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  &:focus {
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #333 inset;
    background-color:#85699A;
    color:#EEE;

    &::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:#DDD; }
    &:-moz-placeholder { color:#DDD; }
    &::-moz-placeholder { color:#DDD; }
    &:-ms-input-placeholder { color:#DDD; }
  }

  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     color: #BBB;
     transition:color 0.5s ease;
  }

  &:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
     color: #BBB;  
     transition:color 0.5s ease;
  }

  &::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
     color: #BBB;  
     transition:color 0.5s ease;
  }

  &:-ms-input-placeholder {  
     color: #BBB;  
     transition:color 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```

Is there any way to shorten / neaten this up using SASS or compass?

Comment: CSS mandates that the rules be separated. I don't think Sass offers a way to compile a group of selectors into separate CSS rules. Also, these are either pseudo-classes or pseudo-elements, not "pseudo-selectors". (That's why Mozilla changed it from `:-moz-placeholder` to `::-moz-placeholder` - simply because it makes more sense as a pseudo-element.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best you can do is abstract your placeholders as a mixin:

```
@mixin placeholder {
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder {
     @content;
  }

  &:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
     @content;
  }

  &::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
     @content;
  }

  &:-ms-input-placeholder {  
     @content;
  }
}

input {
  background-image:url(search.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:20px 20px;
  background-position-x:12px;
  background-position-y:10px;
  background-color:#6E597E;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px #333 inset;
  border-radius:15px;
  border:0;
  padding:8px 10px 10px 45px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:300;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color:#BBB;
  width:100%;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  &:focus {
    outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #333 inset;
    background-color:#85699A;
    color:#EEE;

    @include placeholder { color:#DDD; }
  }

  @include placeholder {  
     color: #BBB;  
     transition:color 0.5s ease;
  }
}
```